# Enable to call C dll in VB.net Code

Tags: c, vb.net, dll, marshalling

I am running into a problem which I am using C Dll into my VB.net code. I have .H file which shows implementation of this DLL in C language.
This .H file contains many structures and unions that contain variable of some structures type. There is a main structure which contains the pointers to these structures and unions and finally address of main structure is passed into the dll function.

I am enable to figure out how to create structures and unions with marshalling in vb.net and how to pass address of a structure which contains addresses of othere structures and unions.

Please me to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, YOgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free tool [CLRInsideOut](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/CLRInsideOut2008_01.exe) that will convert your C structure definitions to VB.NET PInvoke code. Read more [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx). Disclaimer: [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) should really get any rep points for this answer since he [wrote some of the tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2008/03/14/making-pinvoke-easy.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide much detail about your problem I can only help you by directing you to the documentation. You can read more about platform invoke and how to marshal structures and unions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eshywdt7.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Martin for you reply. I read alot about marshalling on Net. and I made structures but the issue is that when I call that dll function it make one structure value to Null but others contain same values as I passed into them prior to fucntion call.

Comment: Maybe that's a function return value?