# Scanning barcode from Windows CE PDA to an ASP.Net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-ce

This might be a very general question but I have researched it and cannot find anything to do what I am looking for. What I am trying to achieve is to have an C# ASP.Net page running on a handheld Windows CE device with barcode scanner. With the device I would like to scan the barcode directly to the ASP.Net webpage without the need to install an application on the device.

My question is, Is it possible to scan direct to an ASP.Net webpage without an installed application?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429557/how-to-access-barcode-scanner-with-vb-net-in-windows-ce

Comment: I have worked with this some time ago, and what I did is to store the information in a SQL CE database, with replication to a SQL database, once the device has connection to internet, the information went directly to the SQL database, therefore consumed by the ASP.Net application